# new instance of class

Tags: class, tkinter

I'm defining a class that creates a LabelFrame using tkinter, with a radio button

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyLabelFrame:
    def __init__(self, master=None,row=0,col=0,label='MyFrame'):
        self.frame = LabelFrame(master, text=label)
        self.frame.grid(row=row,column=col, sticky=(N,S,E,W))
        Label(self.frame,text=label).grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
        self.frame.config(borderwidth = 2)

        MODES = [("Yes", "1"), ("Not", "0")]

        self.value = StringVar()
        self.value.set("Yes")

        for text, mode in MODES:
            self.b = Radiobutton(self.frame, text=text,
                variable=self.value.get(), value=mode)
            self.b.grid(column=0, sticky=(W, E))
            #b.pack(anchor=W)

#####   Tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title("My Root")
##### Create 3 frames
Myframe1 = MyLabelFrame(master=root, row=0, col=0, label='Frame1')
Myframe2 = MyLabelFrame(master=root, row=1, col=0, label='Frame2')
Myframe3 = MyLabelFrame(master=root, row=2, col=0, label='Frame3')
```

[Here is the resulting Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0WDy.png)

The problem is that the buttons are NOT independent, if I set one to YES all three become YES.

I wanted three independent frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
variable=self.value.get()
```

to this:

```
variable=self.value
```

The `variable` option requires an instance of a tkinter variable, not the value of the variable.